# Obtain user information on Actions on Google Through OAuth in AoG?

Tags: api, oauth, actions-on-google

`Account Linking` provides several ways of linking users to their own accounts such as their Google account or Twitter account.

I chose OAuth in `Actions on Google` website to do `OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Grant` for obtaining access token in exchange for data resources. When I linked a user to a Google account `Google Sign-In` enabled, the fetching of user information was easy because the data is stored under `payload`, but OAuth implementation does not seem like it produces user data under `payload` inside `User object`.

So should I make an API call to the third party to fetch the user data and store that personal data to a database in this case? I wondered if there is a way that Google prepares on behalf of developers. If not, then greeting a user who visits my app again by saying 'Hello, {person name}' gets tedious...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options with [Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/).

In the case you describe, you're providing an [OAuth endpoint](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2) and getting an *auth token* from the Assistant, and you are responsible for taking this token and using it to determine who the user is so you can get whatever you know about him. The token is one that *you* issue and control, so presumably you have that info in your database already. If you are reusing a token from another service, that service should be able to tell you who they are.

It sounds like you're using using a Google Sign In, however, in which case it is easier to use [Google Sign In for Assistant](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/google-sign-in). Once the user has signed into your service (either through an app or webapp) and granted permission to your service, then they will also be able to gain access through the Assistant. You will get an *id token* which can be decoded to get profile information about the user including their Google ID and name.